# Neo4j / Cypher node in center of path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a linear path in cypher:

```
MATCH path = (s)-[:SOMETHING*]->(e)
```

What I want is the node in the middle of that path. How can I get it?

Thanks alot for you time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nodes(path)` to get the list of nodes in the path. You can use `length(path)` to get its length, so:

```
MATCH path = (s)-[:SOMETHING*]->(e)
RETURN nodes(path)[length(path)/2] as middle
```

should get you your middle node.